# Is it possible to download the secure file to local machine or view its content in Azure DevOps with build administrator privilege?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, dbt

We have a few already running pipelines in Azure DevOps with dbt orchestration. The profiles.yml file required for the dbt tasks in the pipelines was uploaded to the secure file in DevOps a long time ago.

Now, we have built a new pipeline by orchestrating dbt. As we can't have two profiles.yml files, we are required to update the existing one in the secure file in DevOps.

Also, we have not seen the content of the existing secure file so we are afraid to make the decision to replace the existing file because it would impact the already running pipelines.

Could you please let me know whether we have any possible solution to download the secure file to our local machine or view its content in DevOps if we have the build administrator access?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid that you are not able to directly download the file to local machine.

I suggest that you can use the [Download secure file task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-secure-file?view=azure-devops) to download the secure file and then you can upload the secure file to Build artifacts.

Here is an example:

```
steps:
- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  displayName: 'Download secure file'
  inputs:
    secureFile: Certificates.p12

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(DOWNLOADSECUREFILE.SECUREFILEPATH)'
```

You can find the secure file in Build artifacts.

[image]